# How do I get the value of for loop into another variable

Tags: java, variables, for-loop, user-input

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int x = user.nextInt();

    for(int i= 1; i <= x; x--)
        System.out.println(x + "/" +x + "=" + x/x);
}
```

What I need to do is divde the userinput by the number less than it for example the user enters 9 the program will ouptut:

9/9 = 1, 9/8 = 1.125, and so on up top 9/1;

How would I do that if the same variable is used for the userinput and the loop?

Comment: use the `i` variable?

Comment: Combine values of `x` and `i`. Also `int/int`=`int`, you can change `x` to `double` if you want to get result with floating point like `1.125`.

Comment: for (int i = x; i >= 1; i--) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = user.nextInt();

for(int i = x; i >=1; i--)
    System.out.println(x + "/" +i + "=" + x/(float)i);
```

for the question in the comment:

```
for(int i = x; i >=1; i--){
    if(x%i==0)System.out.println(x + " is divisible by "+i);
}
```

ofcourse this will not print it the way you want it ,but it gives you the idea of what you need to do

Comment: How would I return the divisible numbers and output that. like 9 is divisible by 3 and 1?